# How to make MVC Controller have option to reload or not reload based the button selected on Html.BeginForm

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I am sending the model values with attachments,I have two buttons below the form "Save And Close" and "Save"..when I click on "Save and Close" I want it to reload and navigate to a different controller and action but when I click on "Save"  I want it to remain on the same page Please assist me I tried using ajax,BeginForm it doesn't send out files to my controller when I google they told me about using formData which doesn't work on my case since my application must strictly work on iE.

Hi Below is my Html.BeginForm

```
<div class="grid_section">
    <div class="grid_heading">
        <span class="font_red font_bold">Activity  Detail</span>@*@ViewBag.changeTitle*@
    </div>
    <div class="grid_space">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("ActivitySave", "ActivityMaintenance", FormMethod.Post,
        new 
        {
            enctype = "multipart/form-data",
            name = "frmSaveActivity",                
            id = "frmSaveActivity",
            onsubmit = "return SubmitfrmSaveActivity()"
          }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ActivityId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.OrderNumber)

                if (Model.FirstDocumentPicture != null)
                {
                     <input type="hidden" value="data:image/gif;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.FirstDocumentPicture)" id="firstImg" />
                }
               if(Model.SecondDocumentPicture != null)
                {
                <input type="hidden" value="data:image/gif;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model.SecondDocumentPicture)" id="secondImg" />

                }
                if(Model.DocumentVideo != null)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.DocumentVideo" id="VideoFromDb" />
                }
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>@ViewBag.changeTitle </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Process)</td>
                        <td>
                            @ViewBag.CurrentProcess
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Process)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @*<tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderNumber)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (Model.ActivityId != 0)
                            {
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderNumber, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <p>New</p>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>*@
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ActivityName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.ActivityName, new { @class = "editForm", style = "width: 99%;  height:35px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ActivityName)
                        </td>
                    </tr>                   
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Input)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Input, new { @class = "editForm", style = "width: 99%;  height:35px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Input)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Output)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Output, new { @class = "editForm", style = "width: 99%;  height:35px" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Output)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Responsible)</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Responsible, new { style = "width: 99%; ", @class = "editForm" })

                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Responsible)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SHEQAspects)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SHEQAspects, new { @class = "editForm", style = "width: 99%;  height:35px " })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SHEQAspects)
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
<br />
<div class="square">                         
 Image Caption: @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FirstDocumentPictureCaption, new { @class = "editForm", style = "width: 60%;  height:18px " })<br /><br />
Upload Image : <input style="width: 60%;" type="file" name="uploadedLogo"   id="firstfile"  accept="*" @*onchange="DocumentSizeCheck()"*@ />  <br /><br />
    <div class="gridContent">

        <output id="firstfileList" class="gridTable">

     </output>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="square">
 Image Caption: @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.SecondDocumentPictureCaption, new { @class = "editForm", style = "width: 60%;  height:18px " })<br /><br />
 Upload Image : <input style="width:60%;" type="file" name="uploadedLogo"   id="Secondfile"  accept="*" @*onchange="DocumentSizeCheck()"*@ /> <br /><br />
    <div class="gridContent">
        <output id="SecondFileList" class="gridTable">        
        </output>

    </div>

</div>
<div class="square">
  Video Caption:@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DocumentVideoCaption, new { @class = "editForm", style = "width: 60%;  height:18px " })<br /><br />
  Upload Video :<input style="width:60%;" type="file" name="uploadedLogo"   id="Videofile"  accept="*" /><br /><br />
    <div class="gridContent">
<div controls class="video gridTable"  >
<object classid="clsid:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" width="480" height="330" codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/">
<param id="video_here" name="Filename" value="@Model.DocumentVideo">
<param name="AutoStart" value="false">
<param name="ShowControls" value="true">
<param name="BufferingTime" value="2">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<param name="AutoSize" value="true">
<param name="InvokeURLs" value="false">
<embed  id="video_here"src="@Model.DocumentVideo" type="application/x-mplayer2" autostart="1" enabled="1" showstatusbar="1" showdisplay="1" showcontrols="1" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,0,0,0" width="480" height="360"></embed>
</object>
 </div>

 </div>

 </div>
<div class="buttonsBelow" style="margin-right: 50px;margin-top: 470px;">
            <input class="submitOnNew" type="button" value="Save"  />
            <input  id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Save and Close" />
            <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="CancelfrmSaveActivity()" />
</div>
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

And the MVC C# controller

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ActivitySave(ActivityModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> uploadedLogo)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Cache.SelectedModule() != null && Cache.SelectedModule() is ProcessModel)
                    searchProcessId = ((ProcessModel)Cache.SelectedModule()).Id;

                byte[] firstImage = null;
                byte[] SecondImage = null;
                string DocVideo = "";
                List<byte[]> dataFiles = new List<byte[]>();

                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase i in uploadedLogo)
                {

                    if (i != null)
                    {

                         //var test = new Test.ImpersonateUser();

                            //test.Impersonate("LINDE", "za035d", "Pass1234");

                            var files = uploadedLogo.ToList();
                             var filesd = uploadedLogo.ToList();
                            string FilePath = "";
                            string savePath = @"\\MLGJNB01NETFIL1\ClientApplicationData\AfroxHQMS\";
                            string filename = "";

                            // if directory doesnt exists, create it
                            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(savePath))
                                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);
                            byte[] fileData = new byte[i.InputStream.Length];
                            i.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                            FilePath = Path.GetFileName(i.FileName);  
                            // get file extention
                            int pos = FilePath.LastIndexOf(".");
                            if (pos > 0)
                            {
                                string ext = FilePath.Substring(FilePath.LastIndexOf("."));
                                filename = string.Format(@"{0}" + ext, Guid.NewGuid());
                            }
                            else
                                filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                               //i.SaveAs(savePath + filename);
                               i.SaveAs(savePath + FilePath);


                                if (files[0] != null && (filesd[0] == i))
                                {

                                    firstImage = fileData;
                                }
                                if (files[1] != null && (filesd[1] == i))
                                {
                                    SecondImage = fileData;
                                }
                                if (files[2] != null && (filesd[2] == i))
                                {
                                    string initPath = "file://MLGJNB01NETFIL1/ClientApplicationData/AfroxHQMS/" + FilePath;
                                    DocVideo = initPath;
                                }


                        }



                }
                 ActivityProvider.SaveActivity(model.ActivityId, searchProcessId, model.ActivityName, model.OrderNumber,
                                             model.Input, model.Output, model.Responsible, model.SHEQAspects, firstImage, SecondImage, DocVideo,model.FirstDocumentPictureCaption,model.SecondDocumentPictureCaption,model.DocumentVideoCaption);


                 return View("_ActivityDetail", PopulateActivities(model.ActivityId));
            }
            catch (SecurityException error)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make both buttons submit buttons and give then the same name attribute (say `name="action"`) and different `value` attributes. Then add a extra parameter `string action` in the POST method, and based on the value of `action`, either redirect or return the view.

Comment: Thanks a million Stephen it works now.